# How to send data using jQueryObjet.load(url, data) in script#

Tags: c#, jquery, script#

I have this function in javascript:

```
$('#myElement').load('/some/url/', { parameter1: 0, parameter2: 1 });
```

How can I translate it in Script# ?

At the moment, I am unable to pass the data parameter. I have try this without success:

```
jQueryApi.jQuery.Select("#myElement").Load("/some/url/", "{ parameter1: 0, parameter2: 1 }");
```

The resulted compiled javascript code is (notice the " ' " around the data parameter):

```
$('#myElement').load('/some/url/', '{ parameter1: 0, parameter2: 1 }');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072152/1007232

I needed to create a new class that inherit the Record class.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl

```
$('#myElement').load('/some/url/', { 'parameter1': 0, 'parameter2': 1 });
```

Taking the quotes away from

```
"{ parameter1: 0, parameter2: 1 }"
```

Comment: By taking the quotes away, the line would not compile.

Comment: humm can you give me the error? It defiantly complies. checked the documentation $("#header").load("http://stackoverflow.com", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] } ); is there example. Run this in the console and you'll see it works

Comment: Sure that code run in javascript, but it does not compile in script#.